# Edit action fills form on development but not on staging or production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple form where a user can edit things. If the user goes to the edit action, the form prefills the information it knows. However, this only works on development. On the staging and production server, this does not work.
If the user fills in the empty fields on the edit action, it gets updated as normal.

```
= form_for [@upload, @seller], :url => upload_seller_path(@upload, @seller) do |form|
  = render 'error_messages', :subject => form.object
  %h2 Edit information
  .form-group
    = form.label :first_name
    = form.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control'
  .form-group
    = form.label :last_name
    = form.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control'
  .form-group
    = form.label :address
    = form.text_field :address, class: 'form-control'
  .form-group
    = form.label :city
    = form.text_field :city, class: 'form-control'
  = form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'
  = link_to 'Cancel', upload_seller_path(@upload), class:'btn btn-default'
```

The controller

```
class IncompleteSellersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_upload
  before_filter :set_seller, except: [:index]

  def update
    if @seller.update(sellers_params)
      redirect_to upload_incomplete_sellers_path(@upload)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def set_upload
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:upload_id])
  end

  def set_seller
    @seller = @upload.sellers.find(params[:id])
  end

  def sellers_params
    params.require(:seller).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city)
  end
end
```

I tried adding `value: @seller.address`, but it did not work. 
Any idea where things can go wrong?

Comment: Can you show the relevant controller code and the complete form?

Comment: I added the requested code.

Comment: The code is a bit strange for me, but can you confirm that `@upload` and `@seller` both contain a valid ActiveRecord? In other words... do those have a record?

Comment: Yes. The file that gets uploaded contains a list of sellers. The code saves all the information from the file in the application, and a user can edit the missing information of the seller. So both `@upload` and `@seller` have valid records.

Comment: Also on your production database? Because if you say it works in dev, but not on staging and production, I'm having some doubts. Besides that I'm really wondering why you need a seperate controller for this, why not handle this in the SellersController? Also, if an upload is related to a seller, why not fetch the seller directly? Can you show Seller and Upload model?